# Call function from child class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my python code.

```
class Model:
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        if name is None:
            name = get_apnx_service_name(self.__class__.__name__)
            print("Object created for", name)

        self.url_suffix = "/{name}/".format(name=name)
        self.name = name
        self.apnx_session = sessiona()

    def get_all(self, start_element=0, num_elements=100, method='GET', fields=None, params=None, **kwargs):
        if params is None:
            params = {}

        if is_list(fields):
            params['fields'] = join_list(fields)

        params["start_element"] = start_element
        params["num_elements"] = num_elements

        res = self.apnx_session.request(method, url_suffix=self.url_suffix, params=params, **kwargs)
        return res
class Split(Model):
    def __init__(self, name="/budget-splitter/{li}/splits"):
        super().__init__(name=name)
        self.format_str = name

    def get_all(self, li_id, method='GET', **kwargs):
        self.url_suffix = self.format_str.format(li=li_id)
        #super().get_all(**kwargs)**kwargs)
        #here
```

I needed to change url_suffix in get_all() from Split class.I changed in Split class get_all method.I want to call the output of get_all() in child class.How can i do this.I don't want to do like this solution of writing same code again in Split class.

```
class Split(Model):
    def __init__(self, name="/budget-splitter/{li}/splits"):
        super().__init__(name=name)
        self.format_str = name

    def get_all(self, start_element=0, num_elements=100, method='GET', fields=None, params=None, **kwargs):
        if params is None:
            params = {}

        if is_list(fields):
            params['fields'] = join_list(fields)

        params["start_element"] = start_element
        params["num_elements"] = num_elements

        res = self.apnx_session.request(method, url_suffix=self.url_suffix, params=params, **kwargs)
        return res
```

**SOLVED**
using return super(Split, self).get_all(**kwargs)

Answer (score 0):

What if an extra argument, `li_id`, were added to the constructor for class `Split` and `url_suffix` was initialized during construction (or should I say re-initialized after the base class has already initialized it)? It would then seem that there would be no need to override method `get_all`. Could this work?

```
class Split(Model):
    def __init__(self, li_id, name="/budget-splitter/{li}/splits"):
        super().__init__(name=name)
        self.url_suffix = name.format(li=li_id)
```

Comment: No i can't do this but this solution is also return black response.

Comment: "return black response". What does that mean?

Comment: i meant blank response.